# Hadoop Configuration.addDefaultResource() not working

Tags: configuration, hadoop, configuration-files

My following code does not produce expected output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    Configuration.addDefaultResource("/home/some_user/conf.xml");
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    System.out.println(conf);
    System.out.println(conf.get("color"));
    assertThat(conf.get("color"), is("yellow"));
}
```

The property `color` is set in conf.xml file as follows:

```
<property>
        <name>color</name>
        <value>yellow</value>
        <description>Color</description>
</property>
```

Looks like file `conf.xml` isn't getting incorporated in default configuration.

The documentation for `Configuration.addDefaultResource(String param)` says the param should be in classpath. I don't understand how to add file to the classpath when I am already giving the program full absolute path.

Comment: What happened in the 2 hours since you last asked this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478036/hadoop-configuration-property-returns-null

Comment: @ChrisWhite: I did not know that Configuration.addResource() was deprecated (and hence did not work as I am using newer version of Hadoop). I wanted to try this method too. Your answer for last question did help me, but that was slightly different issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First observation: I don't know which version of hadoop you use but the addDefaultResource() has been deprecated for a very long time.

In the later versions of Hadoop the standard way to accomplish what you want is:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration()
conf.addResource("path/to/file");
...
```

Regarding the classpath issue, you have to simply place the config file in the classpath. So you have to discover what the classpath is to(it is either an environment var or the one which you set with -classpath option). If you didn't use the -classpath option and there is no classpath environment variable then it is automatically set to the current directory (".")

Comment: Passing a string path didn't work for me.  I had to use `conf.addResource(new File("path/to/file").toURI().toURL());`